# Deadlock in a crontab between cron and its child defunct processes

Tags: process, cron, suse

I'm having a strange case of deadlock, where the two processes launched by `cron` are defunct, but `cron` does not pick the return code and exit. I don't have access to the root user.

```
myuser@myserver:~) ps -ef | grep 30163                                  11:29AM
3701     28964 29950  0 11:30 pts/13   00:00:00 grep 30163
root     30163  6622  0 11:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cron
3701     30199 30163  0 11:00 ?        00:00:00 [monitor_daemon] <defunct>
3701     30598 30163  0 11:00 ?        00:00:00 [sendmail] <defunct>
myuser@myserver:~)
```

1. Is there a known reason why we would end up in such a situation?
2. How, without having access to the root user, can I get rid of those three processes that consume memory?

I'm using the following kernel/distribution:

```
Linux myserver 2.6.32.23-0.3-default #1 SMP 2010-10-07 14:57:45 +0200 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
LSB_VERSION="core-2.0-noarch:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-noarch:core-2.0-x86_64:core-3.2-x86_64:core-4.0-x86_64"
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11
PATCHLEVEL = 1
```

Comment: You should check your cron entries and make sure that the commands run as expected. One of the ways to clean defunct is by terminating the parent process. After this, the Parent PID of defunct will become 1. Init should clean defunct process afterwards in a automatic way. Although mentioned you don't have access as root, You need to ask to whom as this access.

Comment: The `<defunct>` processes are [zombies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process). They only consume a few hundred bytes of memory since a zombie is only an entry in the process table, not an actual process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Last SLES11 SP1 kernel when EoL came (2012-11-08) was 2.6.32.59-0.7.

Kernel 2.6.32.23-0.3.1 is from 2010-10-08.

So you are most propably hitting an unfixed OS bug.

Wake up your root-admin and tell him to get his system in shape.

Current supported SLES11 is SP2. Kernel: 3.0.80...

To your second part of the question: You can only get rid of these processes as owner of these (root).